# App Inventor 2 - Text box with subtraction

Tags: app-inventor

Im trying to make an app that'll help me with my job. Basically, I have parts of information like Bearings, speed, range and course, ATB and want them to all add up to a finalised result (doing this is known as an RBROTSARC).

My problem is **I want to use 2 text input boxes that will subtract from each other** (known as Relative Bearing) and display this result in a third and this is only for something called an OSA, eventually there will be other text boxes with either the sin/co sin rule too. **I just need to know how to link the text boxes up so that I can either add, subtract, divide, multiply.**

I will attach my screenshots that I have done so far if this will help, or if anyone fancies the challenge of building this for me I'll be gladly appreciative as I can send you the information that would be used to build it.

[Appinventor2blockscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMb5n.jpg)
[image]

The formulas are

```
relative bearing = abs(target bearing - own bearing)

osa =  sin relative bearing x own speed
```

Comment: Can you explain, what you mean by `2 text input boxes that will subtract from each other`? Do you mean`if textbox1 > textbox2 then calculate textbox1-textbox2 else calculate textbox2 - textbox1` which means `abs(textbox1 - textbox2)`? You might want to provide the formula you like to calculate with...

Comment: well i want to use the text boxes as input sources for the numerical data required. the formula is (sin relative bearing x own speed) so i have to work out the relative bearing first, so for example if tgt bearing is on 090 and we are on bearing 120, the relative bearing is 30, then i have to do another calculation with the speed (sin30 x own speed) to eventually work out what our speed is across the tgts. @Taifun

Comment: I *edited* your question for you to add the formulas to calculate as I understand it. . You might want to correct it. Please also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn, how Stackoverflow works.

Answer (score 1):

> My problem is I want to use 2 text input boxes that will subtract from each other (known as Relative Bearing)

Take 2 textboxes, a label to display the result and a button to start the calculation like this

[image]

Or use global variables like this
[image]
etc. etc.

A very good way to learn App Inventor is to read the free Inventor's Manual here in the AI2 free online eBook   http://www.appinventor.org/book2 ... the links are at the bottom of the Web page.  The book 'teaches' users how to program with AI2 blocks.
There is a free programming course here http://www.appinventor.org/content/CourseInABox/Intro  and the aia files for the projects in the book are here:  http://www.appinventor.org/bookFiles
How to do a lot of basic things with App Inventor are described here:  http://www.appinventor.org/content/howDoYou/eventHandling  .

Also do the tutorials http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/tutorials.html to learn the basics of App Inventor, then try something and follow the [Top 5 Tips: How to learn App Inventor](https://puravidaapps.com/learn.php)

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated, i'll give this a try now. @Taifun